# Script for finding specific file (name and type) and copy to new location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trouble shooting multiple computers with a software that is doing touch calibration. The software is creating `.jpg` files that I need to copy and analyze, however different users have installed the software in different locations making it tidius to search for files. Example on a file would be `002CAL000211.jpg`.

I would like to create a batch file that can do the following:

Search entire `C:` drive with (subfolders) and automatically copy specific files to a set directory based on the the following criteria:

- Filename contains the name "`CAL`"
- Filetype is "`.jpg`"

Preferably I would like the files to be copied to the root of a mounted USB drive.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: creating such script is easy. But it will be very slow. Probably there are specific folders where the search can be focused? Us it created by a program? May it should be searched somewhere in the temp folder (not that some programs use their own temp directories in %appdata%)

Comment: Robocopy would probably be the fastest option.

Comment: `dir /s /b c:\*cal*.jpg` - but as already noted: this is very slow.

Comment: Why do you need help?  What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: `xcopy /S /I "C:\*CAL*.jpg" "X:\"` (supposing `X:` is the USB drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this batch script :

```bat
@echo off
Title Searching for a specific file (name and type) and copy to USB Drive
Mode con cols=90 lines=10 & color 9E
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" ^|find /i ":"') do (Set MyUSB=%%i)
set _drive=%MyUSB%
If defined _drive (
cls
echo.
echo           ---------------------------------------------------------
echo                        Your usb key is connected as !_drive!
echo           ---------------------------------------------------------
echo.
pause
Goto :search
) ELSE (
cls
color 0C
echo.
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo       Your usb key is not detected, please check it and re-run again this script
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
)
pause 
exit

:Search
Cls
echo(
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo              Please Wait a while ....... Searching is in progress .........
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
set "LogSearch=%~dp0%~n0.txt"
set Pattern="*CAL*.jpg"
Where /R C:\ "%Pattern%" /F >"%LogSearch%" 2>&1
If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" (
Cls
echo(
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo                         No file found with this Pattern
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
) else (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%LogSearch%"') do (
        @echo found %%a
        @Copy %%a !_drive!\
    )
)
pause & exit
```

**EDIT : 16/03/2017 @20:00**

```bat
@echo off
Title Searching for a specific file (name and type) and copy to USB Drive
Mode con cols=90 lines=10 & color 9E
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" ^|find /i ":"') do (Set MyUSB=%%i)
set _drive=%MyUSB%
If defined _drive (
cls
echo.
echo           ---------------------------------------------------------
echo                        Your usb key is connected as !_drive!
echo           ---------------------------------------------------------
echo.
pause
Goto :search
) ELSE (
cls
color 0C
echo.
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo       Your usb key is not detected, please check it and re-run again this script
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
)
pause 
exit

:Search
Cls
echo(
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo              Please Wait a while ....... Searching is in progress .........
echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
set "LogSearch=%~dp0%~n0.txt"
If exist "%LogSearch%" Del "%LogSearch%"
set Pattern="CAL" "ERROR"
For %%P in (%Pattern%) Do (
    Where /R C:\ "*%%~P*.jpg" /F >> "%LogSearch%" 2>&1
    If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" (
    Cls
    echo(
    echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo                         No file(s^) found with this Pattern
    echo       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ) else (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%LogSearch%"') do (
            @echo found file %%a
            @Copy /Y %%a !_drive!\
        )
    )
)
pause & exit
```

Comment: Thank you Hackoo - that works like a charm! :) What if I want to add another word to the search (copying files containing "CAL" OR "Error")? Thanks!

Comment: @lox2311 Give a try for my last edit and don't forget to accept this solution as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much!